# How to publish custom artifacts to Artifactory from TeamCity?

Tags: c++, deployment, teamcity, publish, artifactory

I am using Artifactory and TeamCity and have a C++ project that generates binary packages (zip). Using Artifactory TeamCity plugin I am able to publish this artifact but the problem is that it does not end up in the correct tree (organization.module.version.artifact). Next to the zip file I have also an ivy.xml file that contains information about the artifact.

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myorg" module="MyModule"/>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="MyModule" type="zip" ext="zip"/>
    </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

When I look in Artifactory at the Artifact browser the uploaded zip has even no Module-Id.

Any ideas how to tell the TC plugin to make use of this configuration file so that my zip is deployed correctly?

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution for your problem:

1. Make sure that your file is in the right layout after the build, for example
   **workspace..\..com\myorg\MyModule\2.0\MyModule.zip**
2. Use the Ant pattern in the Artifactory plugin, in your case 'workspace.../*.zip=>

   If the right side of the pattern is left empty, the plugin will
   deploy the artifacts maintaining the relative path for each file.

   So in your case, the file will be stored in the Artifactory repository: 
   **repository:com->myorg->MyModule->2.0->somefile.zip**