# how to write file specs for teamcity-artifactory plugin to upload multiple zip files generated as artifacts in build

Tags: file, teamcity, artifactory, specs

unable to upload zip file created as artifacts in teamcity build using file specs to artifactory
tried all types of patterns and file specs unable to upload, it not finding the artifact

```
{
  "files": [{
    "pattern": "**/Batches.zip",
    "target": "repo/Batches.zip",
    "props": "type=zip"
  }]
}
```

Comment: What is the error. Also kindly go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for better understanding of the process followed in SO!

Comment: error is it says 0 artifacts found with pattern

Comment: so the issues is pattern or with the Batches.zip file present in the local file system

Comment: Batches.zip is not in local.. it generated as build artifacts from teamcity.

Comment: my local I meant the filesystem on which whether it exists or not

Comment: it exists.. but still it cannot pick up...not sure why

Comment: @Martin M  saw your post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117100/how-to-publish-custom-artifacts-to-artifactory-from-teamcity?rq=1 , how to use Ant in artifactory plugin?